# pass all fields of model in django filter backend

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter, django-filters

is there any way in which we can `pass all the fields of a model to django filter backend` without explicitly passing the names of fields in search_fields and filter_fields

i have made a generic viewset which serializes all the fields of the model passed to it, but i am facing problem in applying generic filters to it

for eg,

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('username', 'email')
```

in the above code, we have explicitly passed `search_fields` but in my code, i can't pass the fields explicitely as everytime different model may be passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think it's wise to do it, as some fields can reveal sensitive information, but you can try to pass all fields from the model:

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = [f.name for f in User._meta.get_fields()]
```

[Here are the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#django.db.models.options.Options.get_fields) for using `get_fields`:

> ### Options.get_fields(include_parents=True, include_hidden=False)[source]
>
> Returns a tuple of fields associated with a model. `get_fields()`
>   accepts two parameters that can be used to control which fields are 
>   returned:
>
> - **include_parents**
>        `True` by default. Recursively includes fields defined on parent 
>     classes. If set to `False`, `get_fields()` will only search for fields 
>     declared directly on the current model. Fields from models that directly 
>     inherit from abstract models or proxy classes are considered to be 
>     local, not on the parent.
> - **include_hidden**
>        `False` by default. If set to `True`, `get_fields()` will 
>     include fields that are used to back other field’s functionality. This 
>     will also include any fields that have a `related_name` (such as 
>     `ManyToManyField`, or `ForeignKey`) that start with a “+”.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = [field.name for field in User._meta.fields]
```